# How to get unemployed people to work?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have 2000 unemployed in my city, but still many shops and even my fire station is closed because its not enough workers. How do I make my unemployed start working in my fire station??

Comment: One word: Edumucation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically see two major problems with workers.

1. Wealth-class of workers. The break-down of different levels is visible by clicking on the population number at the bottom.  You can raise the wealth-class of your residential areas by placing parks or education facilities.  I'm not sure if education is necessary for fire station or commercial workers, but education certainly keeps middle and upper class Sims happy.
2. Transportation access.  Watch your traffic around 8 am and 5 pm (start and end of work day).  If there's a lot of backed-up traffic, you may need to upgrade roads or place mass transit.

When playing recently, I noticed the traffic problem had gotten a lot better (as opposed to 6-9 months ago).  Usually just upgrading roads and placing buses sufficed for me.